# Emotion detection on text

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am a newbie in ML and was experimenting with emotion detection on the text.
So I have an ISEAR dataset which contains tweets with their emotion labeled.
So my current accuracy is 63% and I want to increase to at least 70% or even more maybe.

Heres the code :

```
inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH, ))

embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size,
                            64,
                            input_length=MAX_LENGTH)(inputs)

# x = Flatten()(embedding_layer)
x = LSTM(32, input_shape=(32, 32))(embedding_layer)
x = Dense(10, activation='relu')(x)

predictions = Dense(num_class, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])

model.summary()
filepath="weights-simple.hdf5"
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
history = model.fit([X_train], batch_size=64, y=to_categorical(y_train), verbose=1, validation_split=0.1, 
          shuffle=True, epochs=10, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty general question, optimizing the performance of a neural network may require tuning many factors.
For instance:

1. The optimizer chosen: in NLP tasks rmsprop is also a popular
   optimizer
2. Tweaking the learning rate
3. Regularization - e.g dropout, recurrent_dropout, batch norm. This may help the model to generalize better
4. More units in the LSTM
5. More dimensions in the embedding

You can try grid search, e.g. using different optimizers and evaluate on a validation set.
The data may also need some tweaking, such as:

6. Text normalization - better representation of the tweets - remove unnecessary tokens (@, #)
7. Shuffle the data before the fit - keras validation_split creates a validation set using the last data records

There is no simple answer to your question.

Comment: Can try adding convolution layer for feature extraction and using pre-trained embedding like GLOVE and Fasttext.